# Add scrollbar to html

Tags: php, html

I have a popup window that with the following source code ("likes.php"):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Like</title>
  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</head>
<body>
<ol>
    <?php for($i=0;$i<500;$i++){ ?>
    <li><p><?php echo $i ?></p></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the problem is that although all the paragraphs are created, I can't see them, because there is no scrollbar. How can I attach a scrollbar to my page?

[Link to printscreen](http://snag.gy/xDK7l.jpg)

It is working on chrome, but not in firefox **IF** it comes in a popup window (other file calls window.open("likes.php"). Works in both browsers in regular windows.

Comment: Browsers add scrollbars automatically. If there aren't any, you must be doing something to hide them. More code is needed to identify the problem.

Comment: @MarkParnell I added the whole code. The scrollbar does not appear

Comment: No CSS? Unless it's your invalid HTML (`<li>` needs to be inside either `<ul>` or `<ol>`, and you can't have `<br>` between them), I can't imagine why there would be no scrollbar. What browser? Can you provide an example link?

Comment: whoa, that is some crazy markup. i would recommend getting  rid of the `<br>` and wrapping your `li`'s in a `ul` or `ol`.

Comment: It's locally stored. I tried with both `ol` and `ul` and removed the <br>, but still there is no scrollbar

Comment: I'll edit the code, add an `ol` and remove the `br`. Sorry for this code, I'm quite a noob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the css `overflow` property. Add this to your `<head>` tag:

```
<style type="text/css">
  body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
  } 
  .scroller {
    overflow: scroll;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

To specifically add a horizontal or vertical scrollbar, use `overflow-x` or `overflow-y`, respectively.

You'll also want to fix the close tag of your `<li>` element, and wrap it in a proper container, like this

```
<div class="scroller">
  <ul>
    <?php for($i=0;$i<500;$i++)
              echo "<li>".$i."</li>";
    ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm a beginner :)

Comment: It still doesn't work in mozilla, IF i open it as a popup. Works otherwise

Comment: I added code that shows the use of a wrapper element to house the scroll bar.

Comment: @p.s.w.g. This PHP is still broken.  It should all be inside one php tag, and you don't need the `<p>` tags

Answer (score 1):

To control overflow, you generally need to use the CSS overflow property

```
overflow: scroll
```

as stated by p.s.w.g., **but you would never need to apply this to the whole body like (s)he suggests**.  The browser should add a scrollbar to the full page on it's own if your code is formatted properly.

The current issue is likely caused by your not closing the second `<li>` tag and by the PHP being improperly formatted.  You don't need a break at the end of each line.  The reason the lines aren't breaking is that you haven't enclosed the `<li>` elements inside an `<ol>` or `<ul>`.  Also, putting the beginning of your if statement, the filler, and the end inside separate php tags will just confuse the computer.  Instead use:

```
  <?php 
    echo "<ul>";
    for( $i=0; $i<500; $i++) { 
      echo "<li>" .  $i . "</li>";
    } 
    echo "</ul>";
  ?>
```

Comment: It will not always display a scrollbar. If the content doesn't extend beyond the edge of the window, most browsers will not apply a scrollbar unless this property is set. (IE being the exception, I think)

Comment: @p.s.w.g. If the content exceeds the bounds of the window, it will default to add scrollbars to the window on any browser I know of.  Adding overflow: scroll to a body tag won't do anything.

Comment: @BujancaMihai I've deleted my comments to avoid cluttering the page. Because this is a question and answer site, it's important to leave a clear answer to anyone who comes across it later.  I'd suggest you delete your comments down here as well because they're unrelated to the original question that I helped you answer.  Good luck with the coding!